# How can I join a table to return all rows right and in addition a null row?

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have two tables, one with a list of parts, and another with a list of attributes. What I'm trying to achieve is to list all parts with their attributes, and also the base row itself a la:

```
Part   Attribute
----------------
Cake   Batman
Cake   Princess
Cake   Spiderman
Cake   NULL

QUERY
----------------
SELECT p.Name, pa.Name
FROM PartsTbl p
LEFT JOIN PartAttrib pa ON p.Name= pa.BaseName
WHERE p.Name = 'Cake'
```

Currently, this only returns everything except the last row. How can I produce the last row as part of the same query, instead of by running a second query?

UPDATE ---------------

```
Table Structure
PartsTbl - Name
PartAttrib - BaseName (To PartsTbl.Name), Name
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the `PartsTbl`.We assume what you have above is `PartAttrib`, but it does not have a `BaseName` column as you used in your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Union is your friend :o)

```
SELECT p.Name, pa.Name
FROM PartsTbl p
LEFT JOIN PartAttrib pa ON p.Name= pa.BaseName
WHERE p.Name = 'Cake'
UNION
SELECT Name, NULL
FROM PartsTbl
WHERE Name = 'Cake'
```